# Rails 4 select helper - how to get only id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this select helper in my view :

```
f.select :employee_id, @employees.collect {|u| [u.id.to_s+':'+u.name+' "'+u.nick+'" '+u.surname]}, {:class => "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle", :multiple => true}
```

It sends form likewise to "id:name "nick" surname", so to get only id from this, I have to use .split(":") function in my controller. It is possible to send only "id" value ? so that I could do something like :
param_id = params[:participant][:id] #=> this should return only **u.id**

EDIT:
Ok, I have that what i wanted :

```
f.select :employee_id, options_for_select(@employees.map{|s|[s.name, s.id]})
```

It returns me only id

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Update your collection so that the elements are as `[text, key]`, so that `key` is used as the value and `text` is used for display text:

```
f.select :employee_id, 
         @employees.collect {|u| [u.id.to_s+':'+u.name+' "'+u.nick+'" '+u.surname, u.id]}, 
         {:class => "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle", :multiple => true}
```

Comment: How can I define this key ? I am trying to do something like this: f.select [:employee_id, :key ], ...

Comment: @bkowalczyyk, can you show your expected html.  Please include this in your question.